# How can I make my deeplearning chatbot use the correct path to my dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, path, dataset, pytorch, chatbot

I am trying to get the code from a deeplearning chatbot to work. This chatbot uses pytorch and the dataset from Cornell movie corpus. But the code can't seem to find the path to the dataset, and I don't know how to code it in. This is the source for the deeplearning chatbot code  [https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/tutorials/blob/gh-pages/_downloads/chatbot_tutorial.ipynb][1]

This is as far as I've gotten with it.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import torch
from torch.jit import script, trace
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import csv
import random
import re
import os
import unicodedata
import codecs
from io import open
import itertools
import math


USE_CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device("cuda" if USE_CUDA else "cpu")

corpus_name = "cornell movie-dialogs corpus"
corpus = os.path.join("data", corpus_name)

def printLines(file, n=10):
    with open(file, 'rb') as datafile:
        lines = datafile.readlines()
    for line in lines[:n]:
        print(line)

printLines(os.path.join(corpus, "movie_lines.txt"))
```

And this is my error log

```
D:\Documents\Python\python pycharm files\pythonProject4\3.9 Chatbot.py:26: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  corpus = "D:\Documents\Python\intents\cornell_movie_dialogs_corpus.zip\cornell movie-dialogs corpus\\"("data", corpus_name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Python\python pycharm files\pythonProject4\3.9 Chatbot.py", line 26, in <module>
    corpus = "D:\Documents\Python\intents\cornell_movie_dialogs_corpus.zip\cornell movie-dialogs corpus\\"("data", corpus_name)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I hope there is a solution that doesn't alter the source code too much, but any tips or help are welcome.

Comment: Your error does not match the code, and when I run your code locally it has no problem (I have created a txt file with some text).

Comment: Any idea what would cause a mismatch like that? My best guess is a broken or missing library but I don't know what it could be.

Comment: is this: D:\Documents\Python\python pycharm files\pythonProject4\3.9 Chatbot.py the file you posted?

Comment: Yes thats the location of the code that I posted within pycharm

Comment: Then it is the error of this code, but it is very weird, because the line (not number of line) which it says that has an error does not appear in the code you posted.

Comment: Can you comment here line 26 of your code? (copy it from pycharm and not from this question).

Comment: corpus = os.path.join("data", corpus_name)

Comment: It works for me too; perhaps a stupid suggestion, but did you unzip the zip before you started working on the files? (windows accepts alterations on unzipped files).

Comment: I had it zipped tried the code then unzipped it and tried to run the code again

Comment: I solved my problem by removing anything but the cornell movie-dialogs corpus map. And then replacing the word "data" in line 26 with the directory of that map. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing anything but the cornell movie-dialogs corpus map. And then replacing the word "data" in line 26 with the directory of that map. This fixed it for me